# Pandas to excel not working - missing libraries?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having some issue in my virtual environment trying to write a DataFrame to excel. I am pretty certain it's a libraries issue but can't pin point what library I'm missing. I would like to eventually deploy this script out and don't want to package my entire Anaconda library as well as a requirement. I have tried running these same lines in a juypter notebook and it works so I am definitely missing some library in my virtual env.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel(file_path.strip('\"'), index_col = 0, usecols = use_col)               
print(df)

df.to_excel("test.xlsx")
```

I am running Python 3.8.4 and running `pip freeze` in my virtual env, I can see the following:

```
et-xmlfile==1.1.0
numpy==1.21.4
openpyxl==3.0.9
pandas==1.3.5
python-dateutil==2.8.2
pytz==2021.3
pyxlsb==1.0.9
six==1.16.0
xlrd==2.0.1
XlsxWriter==3.0.2
xlwt==1.3.0
```

According to Panadas website, I should have all the requirements for excel writing but what am I missing??
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/install.html#excel-files

Comment: Edit the question to explain "sone issue". If there is an error message show it as properly formatted text.

Comment: What is the error popping up? If there is no error message than the test.xlsx file is probably somewhere where you didn't expect it

Comment: @Kylian I'm an idiot, you're correct. Just noticed the path run on my Visual studio is different. Problem solved, thanks!